# Creating a new form, switching focus between the new and the old form with a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and I want to get an instance of the same form as stated in the code below. And I have a button: every time I press this button, if a new form is created, I want it to focus to that window, if not, I want to create a new form.

I managed to create a new form but if I want to focus on it, the code did not work, any ideas?

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (opened == false)
  {
    Text = "form1";
    var form = new myformapp();
    form.Show();
    opened = true;
    form.Text = "form2";
  }
  else
  {
    if (Application.OpenForms[1].Focused)
    {
      Application.OpenForms[0].BringToFront();
      Application.OpenForms[0].Focus();
    }
    if (Application.OpenForms[0].Focused)
    {
      Application.OpenForms[1].BringToFront();
      Application.OpenForms[1].Focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Button "btn" located is it in First Form or Second Form or on Both Forms?

Comment: both forms.Acutally if a new form is opened i want it to switch focus,if not i want it to create a new form.

Comment: ShowDialog can be used instead

Comment: And the Variable "opened". Is it a Static Variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try shortening your code without the need to introduce more variables with this example:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  bool found = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; ++i) {
    if (Application.OpenForms[i].GetType() == typeof(myformapp) &&
        Application.OpenForms[i] != this) {
      Application.OpenForms[i].Select();
      found = true;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    myformapp form = new myformapp();
    form.Show();
  }
}
```

Updated code from Francesco Baruchelli's comment.

Comment: It doesn't work, since it always selects the form executing button1_Click and it will never open a second instance of myformapp. I would add `&& Application.OpenForms[i] != this` to your if condition

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli Ugh.  I missed the part where the two forms are the "same" form.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can keep a static List with the opened forms. Everytime an instance of your Form is opened you add it to the List, and everytime it is closed you remove it. The when you press the button you can check the size of the List. If it is 1 you create a new Form, open it and set the focus on it. If the size is already 2, you look in the List for the instance which is different from the one executing the click event. The code could be something like this:

```
    private static List<Form1> openForms = new List<Form1>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = null;
        if (openForms.Count == 2)
        {
            foreach (Form1 aForm in openForms)
                if (aForm != this)
                {
                    frm = aForm;
                    break;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();
        }
        frm.Focus();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openForms.Add(this);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        openForms.Remove(this);
    }
```